# Objective C: Timer crashes app when turned on a second time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

I have my NSTimer declared in the header file. When the `play` button is tapped, it turns on the timer. Next tap disables timer. A third tap crashes the app with no error message. Why would this be happening?

```
-(IBAction) play {

if ([col1 isValid]) {
    [col1 invalidate];
} else {
    col1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.8 target:self selector:@selector(playCol1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`invalidate` will cause the object to be released. So, you are attempting to call `isValid` on a bad reference. nil out the `col1` object after you invalidate it, and you should be fine.

```
-(IBAction) play {

    if ([col1 isValid]) {
        [col1 invalidate];
        col1 = nil;
    } else {
        col1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.8 target:self selector:@selector(playCol1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: To be technical, `invalidate` will allow the run loop to release the timer. It doesn't release the timer itself.

Comment: Continuing the point, the error is that the OP did not retain col1. This code can crash if `-play` is called after the timer has fired or otherwise been invalidated. Don't rely on others to retain things for you; retain your own ivars unless there's a very good reason not to (such as delegates).

Answer (score 2):

Crash is because it is trying to `invalidate` an already invalidated timer `col1`.

Did you try `[col1 isValid]==YES`?
 Try out that and if that doesn't work then try using an custom `integer` or `BOOL` type flag.

I had a similar problem with the `isValid` Method and made a workaround for it by using flag of BOOL type

Hope this helps you.

**SAMPLE OF USAGE OF CUSTOM FLAGS:**

```
 BOOL invalidateTimer = NO; 
-(IBAction) play 
{
     if (invalidateTimer == YES) 
     {
                 [col1 invalidate];
     }
     else if (invalidateTimer == NO)
     {
           col1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.8 target:self selector:@selector(playCol1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
           invalidateTimer = YES;
     }
}
```